# Looping through a tags and changing url via .click

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a total noob in using selenium-webdriver -- please apologize for obvious/simple mistakes ;-)

I'm trying to loop through the  tags of a website. Whenever I call 'click' on the looped a-tag, the opened up test-browser jumps to new page. Afterwards the 'starting'-page will be loaded via navigate().back().

As long as no new page has been loaded -- everything works fine, but afterwards cur_href and cur_text display 'undefined'.

Are the elements in the for-loop loosing their reference (to the tag-objects)? Why is that happening?

```
for (el of elems) {

    let cur_href = await el.getAttribute('href').catch(()=>console.log('no elem?'));
    let cur_text = await el.getText().catch(()=>console.log('no elem?'));

    await el.click().catch(()=>{
      //text
    });

    await chrome_driver.navigate().back();    
}
```

Comment: When you leave the current page (or the page or partial page refreshes) and you have a variable pointing to an element on the page, those references are lost. Generally when you try to use them, you will get a stale element exception. The way to get around that is to not loop through `elems` but to put your fetch code there (driver.findElements(), etc) so that when the loop gets hit, it refetches the list fresh.